# Negative Log Likelihood for Censored Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, survival-analysis

I'd like to use negative log likelihood as an objective function to model roughly gaussian data with right censoring. My objective function will look something like the following, but I'm not sure how to come up with the standard deviation used for the calculation. Normally we just minimize RMSE for gaussian maximum likelihood and the standard deviation reduces to some constant that we can safely ignore. When calculating the likelihood with censored data using 1 - CDF it's not clear that the standard deviation isn't important. Is it safe to just use the standard deviation of the response variable as the standard deviation here?

I don't really want to model using the concordance index, and I'd prefer to use non-parametric techniques rather than simple cox proportional hazards models.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
def censored_nll(event, value, prediction, std_dev):
    if event:
        return -np.log(norm.pdf(value, prediction, std_dev))
    return -np.log(norm.sf(value, prediction, std_dev))
```

Comment: My advice is to bite the bullet and write out the full n.l.l. and maximize with respect to both mu and sigma^2. Some kind of stepwise scheme in which you optimize wrt to mu first and then sigma^2 and then mu again, etc., is probably defensible. This is a good question but probably more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to just use the standard deviation of the response variable as the standard deviation here?

Definitely not, the observed distribution is not suitable for computing summary statistics because of the right censored data points.

You must compute the MLE numerically for both the mean and standard deviation. Your code is half-way there, but let me give you a hand:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def censored_nll(params, events, durations):
    mu, std_dev = params
    observed_durations = durations[events==1] # or events==True
    censored_durations = durations[~(events==1)] # or events==True
    return -(np.log(norm.pdf(observed_durations, loc=mu, scale=std_dev)).sum() \
             + np.log(norm.sf(censored_durations, loc=mu, scale=std_dev)).sum())

scipy.optimize.minimize(censored_nll, x0=np.array([0,1]), args=(events, durations))
```

Comment: Thanks Cam. For more context I'd like to use this negative log-likelihood function as an objective function to fit a non-parametric model, not just computing summary statistics.

Comment: I’m curious about how you are building a non parametric model with a parametric likelihood?

Comment: Non-parametric model as in random forest or gradient boosted trees vs something like a linear model. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147587/are-random-forest-and-boosting-parametric-or-non-parametric